# PHP - weird, non-consistent results from pow()

Tags: php, exponential

I have this line in 2 different files but in the same application.

```
pow(36, 8);
```

One returns -INF while the other returns 2821109907456

Is there any external factors that I am not aware of that causes this? Because I don't see the inputs as the problem since they are exactly the same.

EDIT: The code which returns -INF is enclosed in a foreach. Thought that might give us a clue why this happens.

EDIT 2:
The loop looks like this

```
foreach($items as &$item)
{
  foo($item['some_index'], ... , ..., ...);
}
unset($item);
```

The function that the loop calls is something like

```
function foo($input, $a, $b, $c)
{
   ....
   $x = pow(36, 8);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Is run on a 32 bit system and the other on a 64 bit platform?

Comment: Both codes are on the same 32-bit system.

Comment: Can we see the foreach loop for context?

Comment: @Phoenix added it in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of an integer is platform-dependent and you may be reaching the max. Try using the BC Math function [bcpow](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcpow.php) in place of `pow`

Comment: bcpow() returns the value correctly. But I am more interested on learning the cause of the pow() inconsistency.

Comment: the max size of an int on a 32bit system is 2147483647. You are well over this and will get int overflow, hence the "random" results.